# 4th BottomNavigationBarItem overrides color

Tags: flutter

The code below works as expected. However, if I uncomment the fourth BottomNavigationBarItem the appbar background color overrides the indigo backgroundColor and turns white. I don't understand why the addition of an item is causing this. Ideas?

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  static List<Widget> pages = const <Widget>[
    NewEntryScreen(),
    TodaysReviewScreen(),
    AllEntriesScreen(),
    SettingsScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppStateManager>(
      builder: (
        context,
        appStateManager,
        child,
      ) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              'Most Learned',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
            ),
          ),
          body: IndexedStack(
            index: widget.currentTab,
            children: pages,
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
            selectedItemColor:Colors.orange,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.teal,
            currentIndex: widget.currentTab,
            onTap: (index) {
              Provider.of<AppStateManager>(context, listen: false)
                  .goToTab(index);
            },
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.emoji_objects), label: 'New'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.access_time), label: 'Daily'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.toc), label: 'All'),
              // BottomNavigationBarItem(
              //     icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: 'Settings'),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You marked the list as const (which means the list is compile-time constant), maybe this is a problem related to the hot-reload of your emulator. Try restarting it or mark the list as final (run-time constant).

Comment: Restarting (as opposed to hot reload) produces the same results.
Sorry for the remedial question, but how do I change to final? I replaced const with final and get the error "Expected and identifier"

Comment: As an aside, I was able to solve the UI problem by moving the background argument from the bottomNavigationBar and calling it on each of the 4 BottomNavigationBarItem, but it seems like a hack. I'm still curious what the underlying issue is.

Comment: Solved: Dug into Flutter's bottom_navigation_bar.dart. 4 or more items default to BottomNavigationBarType: 'shifting' whereas 3 or less default to type 'fixed'. Each of these types defaults to a different background color (white vs ColorScheme.primary) if the individual items' background colors are null. A logical reason for this makes no sense to me, but mystery solved!

Comment: You can´t direclty set it to final in this case (it would be possible if you store a list in a final variable) - also please post your answer as an anser and accept it for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Four or more items default to BottomNavigationBarType: 'shifting' which in turn defaults to background color ColorScheme.primary when the individual item is null.

Three or less default to type 'fixed' which defaults to white when item is null.

Not sure why the change is necessary, but...

Flutter's bottom_navigation_bar.dart:

```
///  * [BottomNavigationBarType.fixed], the default when there are less than
///    four [items]. The selected item is rendered with the
///    [selectedItemColor] if it's non-null, otherwise the theme's
///    [ColorScheme.primary] color is used for [Brightness.light] themes
///    and [ColorScheme.secondary] for [Brightness.dark] themes.
///    If [backgroundColor] is null, The
///    navigation bar's background color defaults to the [Material] background
///    color, [ThemeData.canvasColor] (essentially opaque white).
///  * [BottomNavigationBarType.shifting], the default when there are four
///    or more [items]. If [selectedItemColor] is null, all items are rendered
///    in white. The navigation bar's background color is the same as the
///    [BottomNavigationBarItem.backgroundColor] of the selected item. In this
///    case it's assumed that each item will have a different background color
///    and that background color will contrast well with white.
```